# <picture> element flickering to 100% width between media queries/attributes

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

So I've an absolutely positioned hero image that I'm allowing to overflow its container as the browser is made smaller (for parallax reasons I want to maintain its height).

I've used the picture element to add cropped versions of the image at given breakpoints in order to achieve this. I've also set the wrapper's width attribute to 100%;

```css
.wrapper {
  position: relative;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.image {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  content: "";
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <picture>
    <source media="(max-width: 1200px)" srcset="https://i.imgur.com/Be8mwYF.jpg 1200w" width="1200">
    <source media="(max-width: 1500px)" srcset="https://i.imgur.com/uyRlf1V.jpg 1500w" width="1500">
    <source srcset="https://i.imgur.com/jZkIwzu.jpg 1903w" width="1903">

    <img src="https://i.imgur.com/jZkIwzu.jpg" alt="" class="image">
  </picture>


</div>
```

This works as I'd expect, except as I reduce the browser size and it hits the media breakpoint the image very briefly flickers and behaves as if `width` was set to 100% again; The reverse is also true - when making the browser large, at the breakpoints the image momentarily zooms in.

This behaviour only happens for a split second, and it doesn't seem possible to make it remain at that size. I've almost no styling on the element, so I don't think that's the issue.

I've tried to create a code example, but codepen seems to ignore that the image should overflow the container (unless I'm missing something), [here](https://codepen.io/nwoodward/pen/LYjzGJK?editors=1111), and the results panel of stackoverflows' editor (above) seems too small to demonstrate the problem

Anyone have any ideas where I might be going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

So the answer seems to be setting the width of the image to `auto`. But I've still no real idea why it behaves this way between breakpoints :shrug:

Hopefully this helps someone else if they come across the same thing